# change Badge and push notification in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, push-notification, badge

I tried the [push notification tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services) . It's working fine but problem is badge. When I click on the view, app is appear and the close it. it still red badge in app icon. How to remove it ?

Another question is

when I click the view, it will appear home screen. I want to show other view when coming from push notification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will reset the [application badge number](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  If you set that value to zero, it will hide the badge.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = iCount;
```

To handle your push notification with a separate view, you need to handle the following message in your application delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

You can access the *userInfo* dictionary to get additional information about the push notification that resulted in the message callback.