# How to create badge number with parse on ios device?

Tags: ios5, ios6, xcode4.5, badge, parse-platform

I'm try to create the push notification on my app, and using this script paste on application didReceiceRemoteNotification function:

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    messageContent, @"alert",
    @"Increment", @"badge",
    nil];
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setChannel:chatRoomName];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

But, I just can show the push message, there are no badge number show on my app right corner.. what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

for setting badge number you need to refere below url. that will give your required ans.

[change Badge and push notification in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956585/change-badge-and-push-notification-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: It's still can't work. Is there are specific function use for parse.com push notification function? 

I just reference on this:
http://blog.parse.com/2012/07/18/badge-management-for-ios/